# FINGERPRINT_ERROR_LOCKOUT callback happening twice using Android Native API

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I am implementing the android native fingerprint API for one of our applications.
Below is the code of the handler:

```
 public class FingerprintHandler extends
            FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback {

        private CancellationSignal cancellationSignal;
        private Context appContext;
        private boolean sendCancellation=false;

        public FingerprintHandler(Context context) {
            appContext = context;
        }
        public void startAuth(FingerprintManager manager,
                              FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject) {

            cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(appContext,
                    Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            manager.authenticate(cryptoObject, cancellationSignal, 0, this, null);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(int errMsgId,
                                          CharSequence errString) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Authentication error callback");
            Log.d(TAG,"Error Value: "+errMsgId);
            switch(errMsgId){
                case FINGERPRINT_ERROR_LOCKOUT:
                    Log.d(TAG,"Fingerprint error lockout");
                    nativeLocked = true;
                    mPreferences.edit().putLong(LAST_FAILURE, System.currentTimeMillis()).apply();
                    showError(getString(R.string.test_bio_fingerprint_fingerprint_authentication_failed));
                    mCancelButton.setEnabled(true);
                    dialogHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mCancelButton.setEnabled(true);
                            dismissDialog();
                            sendFailure();

                        }
                    }, SUCCESS_OR_FAIL_DELAY_MILLIS);
                    break;
                case FINGERPRINT_ERROR_CANCELED:
                Log.d(TAG,"Fingerprint has been cancelled");
                if(sendCancellation) {
                    dismissDialog();
                    if (useEye)
                        sendCancelForEye();
                    else
                        sendCancel();
                }
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpMsgId,
                                         CharSequence helpString) {

            Log.d(TAG,"Authentication helper callback");
            retryWithError(R.string.test_bio_fingerprint_fingerprint_too_fast);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
            Log.d(TAG,"Authentication failed callback");
            retryWithError(R.string.test_bio_fingerprint_fingerprint_not_recognized);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
                FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Authentication successfull callback");
            onAuthenticationSuccess();

        }
        public void stopListening(boolean sendCancellation) {
            this.sendCancellation=sendCancellation;
            Log.d(TAG,"stopListening called");
            if (cancellationSignal != null) {
                cancellationSignal.cancel();
                cancellationSignal = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when there are 5 incorrect authentication attempts I can see the below in my logs:

```
Authentication error callback
Error Value: 7
Fingerprint error lockout
Authentication error callback
Error Value: 7
Fingerprint error lockout
```

The lockout call back gets twice. I am unable to figure out why this is happening. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check errMsgId because first is triggered for your action callback and second time is triggered for "Fingerprint operation canceled."
Also please notice that FingerPrintManager is deprecated  and for the new api for BiometricPrompt the implementation should look like example below (you need to replace BiometricConstants.ERROR_NEGATIVE_BUTTON with your action id code):

```
 @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode,
                                          @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
            if (BiometricConstants.ERROR_NEGATIVE_BUTTON == errorCode) {
                //do your job only once
            }
        }
```